# Codeigniter3: How to check database record existance in a folder or directory?

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I want to compare database record with a folder or directory in Codeigniter, so I can check whether the record id from database exists in folder or directory of codeingiter. 
Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Using these code you will get the directory listing:

```
function getDir($dir_path='*'){
          $dirs = array_filter(glob($dir_path), 'is_dir');
            $directory = array();
            foreach ($dirs as $item => $key ) {
                array_push($directory, $key);
            }
            return $directory;
    }
```

Note: Make sure that you function `getDir()` is a Helper function

call function `getDir()` in your controller

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Home extends Admin_Controller{
    public function __construct() {
        parent :: __construct();
        $this->load->model('database_model_name');
    }


    public function index() {

        $dir_array=getDir(); //only directory listing make it recursive to get folder details  
        $db_dir_array = $this->database_model_name->getDir();

        // Compare both the array and do whatever you want to  

    }
}
?>
```

May be it will help you .